# Sketch: how to merge shapes?

Tags: shapes, path, sketch-app

I am pretty new to Sketch. I am currently trying to merge two shapes into a single one. However whenever I hit "union" it does "merge" them, though basically they are still separate paths, that are just grouped together:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, should've spent more time on the official website ...

> **Flattening Shapes**
>
> When you flatten a shape in Sketch, it will try to represent the
>   multiple paths inside the shape as one path; it will, so to speak,
>   ‘flatten’ the hierarchy. However there are many paths that can’t be
>   flattened into one. A shape with a hole inside it will always have to
>   be represented as two paths; one for outer path, and one for the inner
>   path.
>
> When Sketch cannot flatten a path it will warn when you try to do so.
>   If you persist, the subpaths you had will be replaced by different
>   subpaths.
>
> If you’re used to other design tools, you may automatically look to
>   flatten a path after you have applied a boolean operation. In Sketch
>   there’s no need for that; you can apply as many boolean operations on
>   top of one-another keeping each subpath independent and editable.

- [www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/shapes/boolean-operations](https://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/shapes/boolean-operations/)